# eclipse crashing on launch (opensuse linux)

Tags: eclipse, crash, glib, launch, suse

After some updates to linux, including a kernel update, Eclipse won't start at anymore.
Starting from command line only gets me a bunch of warning messages, but then simply stops.
Afaik, the updates are the only thing that may have changed the system.

Operating system is OpenSuse 15.1 linux (4.12.14-lp151.28.52-default kernel). Eclipse is oxygen 4.7, Java openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14.

kde4-config -v says
Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.38
kde4-config: 1.0

Gtk is 3.22.30-lp151.6.6.1

Output from command line run

```
(Eclipse:8147): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:68:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
```

*repeats 6 times with varying gtk.css:xx:yy*

```
(Eclipse:8147): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
```

*repeats 224 times*

then 2 times the first group of messages (12 messages in total),
and again

```
(Eclipse:8147): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
```

*repeats 224 times*

At last, I get

```
Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$1
```

I have no clue what has happened to my Eclipse installation aside from mentioned updates, which did not enclose any updates for Eclipse. Don't know, if the warnings have been present before, because I usually do not start Eclipse from the command line.

I have searched the internet for the most part of the day, not getting much further.
The GLib-critical warnings were mentioned with a Ubuntu upgrade of Gtk+, but I could not make a connection to my specific case.
A hint on Eclipse's workspace log had me take a look (I'm really sorry for posting the wrong log before). The original log files from a single eclipse start are > 4MB, so I will post only the first lines.

```
    !SESSION 2020-06-15 12:10:03.594 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
java.version=11.0.7
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

This is a continuation of log file /home/heinrich/workspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2020-06-15 12:10:20.886

!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core 2 1 2020-06-15 12:10:20.886
!MESSAGE AERI failed with an error. Please report this error: null ; version: 2.0.7.v20170906-1327
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.contains(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.di.SystemSettingsCreationFunction.loadFromPreferences(SystemSettingsCreationFunction.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.di.SystemSettingsCreationFunction.compute(SystemSettingsCreationFunction.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ValueComputation.get(ValueComputation.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.internalGet(EclipseContext.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier.fillArgs(ContextObjectSupplier.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier.get(ContextObjectSupplier.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveArgs(InjectorImpl.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:220)
```

... continues

The continuations of the log files seem to make a cyclic reference, so 
I'm not really sure that this is the beginning.

Tried
 - eclipse -clean
 - eclipse -initialize
which changed essentially nothing.

As a kind of last resort I installed 2020-03 and launched it on a workspace copy (that is where the log is from), which seemed OK.
*edit*
Repeating the "experiment" with a workspace copy showed basically the same results as with oxygen. 2020-03 started on a clean workspace (empty directory) ran properly. Found out how to launch oxygen with a different workspace. It showed all the Gtk & GLib-Critical warnings, but properly came up with a welcome screen. So I think it definitely has something to do with the workspace content.
*tide*

*edit2*
To find some kind of root cause, I created a workspace from backup data (from last week, where all had been running smoothly). While it worked, I copied the its .metadata/ directory chunk by chunk to the failing workspace and tried oxygen after each step. After all files copied, which I thought would eventually repair the failing WS, oxygen still didn't start.
With some try 'n error I found out that the *good* workspace was turned into a *bad* one just by running oxygen. After still more back and forth copy/delete/restore it seems that it is enough to restore the file `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` from backup to make oxygen startup, but there never is a second second run succeeding.

Currently I am not able to change SWT Themes, as marketplace doesn't show up actually.

To rule out dependencies with desktop themes, I changed them several times, again, with no success.

*2tide*

I'm out of ideas now.
Any help appreciated to get Eclipse running again.

Comment: Your reported Eclipse build ID differs from Oxygen pretty greatly. Which version of gtk do you have after those recent updates?

Comment: `eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155` is Eclipse 2020-03 **not** Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: Which GTK version do you have? Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15) requires GTK 3.14 or higher (upcoming release on Wednesday will require GTK 3.20 or higher).

Comment: I'm truely sorry for posting the wrong log file here. The posted one was from an experiment with 2020-03, which you identified, of course. Thanks for that.

Comment: Seems to be a [GTK bug according to this comment here and maybe related to the theme you are using](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530781#c5).

Comment: Thank you very much, howlger, for the hint to the SWT  issue. I will see to it when either marketplace is available or I find another way to change themes.